# Notification Bar information about battery

Tags: android

How to add information about the Notification Bar at the battery?

Text can be added but I can not add downloaded battery.

Answer (score 0):

Well you provided not much information what you want to do. So I guess you want to create background Service that manipulates its status bar icon to display the battery status. Therefore I suggest the following sites about Android Services and the Status Bar Notifications.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

If there are still questions feel free to ask.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean exactly those appearing on the notification bar.
https://lh3.ggpht.com/ZKaSQ1xmJBV_RZVSOTS6kFIAMLV3nivGPWOqCzJ5-0WU4XBeLN9OZZXcegDE5WLwNgs

Comment: Yes. That is the notification you see in my second link. But You need a Context for a notification. That means a service or activity.

Answer (score 0):

dude this is a code of Notification

```
  NotificationManager notifi = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

   Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Testing",System.currentTimeMillis());

   notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

   Intent i = new Intent(this,KillerActivity.class); 

   PendingIntent penInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0 , i , 0);

   notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "Varaha ", "Testing", penInt);

   notifi.notify(215,notification);
```

here 215 is Unique id which is Associated with Notification Bar

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,KillerActivity.class);
```

here KillerActivity.class is the name of the class  on which intent u want to Display Notification

Comment: I mean a display battery level, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

use this code that will get you the amount of battery used, the battery voltage, and its temperature.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    BroadcastReceiver batteryReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        int scale = -1;
        int level = -1;
        int voltage = -1;
        int temp = -1;
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
            scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
            temp = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, -1);
            voltage = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, -1);
            Log.e("BatteryManager", "level is "+level+"/"+scale+", temp is "+temp+", voltage is "+voltage);
        }
    };
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(batteryReceiver, filter);
}
```

// use this code to post notification

```
NotificationManager notifi = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

   Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Testing",System.currentTimeMillis());

   notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

   Intent i = new Intent(this,KillerActivity.class); 

   PendingIntent penInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0 , i , 0);

   notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "Varaha ", "Testing", penInt);

   notifi.notify(215,notification);
```

Merge above code snippets in an activity you will get desired result